# RestAssured: unable to parse response for required value using Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, soap, rest-assured

I need a little help getting used to Rest Assured.

I have a request that I am building as a String (these tests are necessarily simplified for the time being as will be maintained by testers so utilising more advanced concepts like JAXB is on the back burner).

`String request = myPayRequest.searchPaymentOptions(dataObject);`

The String I am passing is actually a Soap envelope which looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
<searchPaymentOptions xmlns="http://website.stuff.com">
  <header xmlns="">
    <ns1:credentials organisation="stuff" password="password" username="foobar" xmlns:ns1="http://website.stuff.com"/>
    <ns2:invocationDetails system="FindAndBook" trackingId="qqdG6jVIqIkw459wSj0ymokh" type="NATIVE" xmlns:ns2="http://website.stuff.com"/>
  </header>
  <criteria xmlns="">
    <performFundingCheck>false</performFundingCheck>
    <preferredPayment>
      <productSupplier>
        <ns3:thingyCode xmlns:ns3="http://website.stuff.com">ABC</ns3:thingyCode>
      </productSupplier>
      <requiredFunds amount="35.63" currency="GBP"/>
    </preferredPaymentCriterions>
  </criteria>
</searchPaymentOptions>
```

RESPONSE:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <ns2:preferredPaymentSearch xmlns:ns2="http://website.com">
        <header>
            <issueAudit>
                <info>
                    <issues>
                        <issue host="website/10.2.333.46" issueCode="Host" issueId="b5b006c7-42b6-4d8c-8e07-c2f2e1634a9e" issueMessage="website/10.2.333.46" severity="INFO" timestamp="2017-03-23T13:04:53.106Z"/>
                        <issue host="website/10.2.333.46" issueCode="TrackingId" issueId="38f73e0d-5c42-415b-b88d-1aba098e1a59" issueMessage="qqdG6jVIqIkw459wSj0ymokh" severity="INFO" timestamp="2017-03-23T13:04:53.106Z"/>
                    </issues>
                </info>
                <warnings>
                    <issues/>
                </warnings>
                <errors>
                    <issues/>
                </errors>
            </issueAudit>
            <status>SUCCESS</status>
            <ver>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</ver>
        </header>
        <results>
            <preferredPaymentResults>
                <preferredPaymentCriterion>
                    <productSupplier>
                        <ns2:actorCode>ABC</ns2:actorCode>
                    </productSupplier>
                    <requiredFunds amount="35.63" currency="GBP"/>
                </preferredPaymentCriterion>
                <preferredPaymentOption>
                    <preferredCardOption>
                        <cardForm>GENERATABLE</cardForm>
                        <cardType>VISA_CREDIT</cardType>
                        <provider>wibble</provider>
                    </preferredCardOption>
                </preferredPaymentOption>
            </preferredPaymentResults>
        </results>
    </ns2:preferredPaymentSearch>
</soap:Body>
```

The response should & does contain a SOAP envelope with the following snippet  `<status>SUCCESS</status>`

When I try the following:

```
   String response = given().body(request)
            .when().post().andReturn().asString();

    expect().body(hasXPath("//soap:Body//*[name()='status']", equalTo("FAILURE")));
```

...then the test passes even when SUCCESS is the data value

Likewise I have tried to use a different syntax but this also gives a false positive:

```
    given().config(newConfig().xmlConfig(xmlConfig().with().namespaceAware(true)));
    given().body(request).post();
    expect().body(hasXPath("//soap:Body//*[name()='status']", equalTo("SUCCESS")));
```

Where am I going wrong? I shouldn't actually need to read the Response in as a String I believe so example one may be smelly. But example 2 also passes but should fail.

Comment: In hasXPath(), don't you mean `soapenv:Body` instead of `soap:Body`?

Comment: possibly - but that still doesn't explain why the tests are passing when the Response does not contain the expected xpath value

Comment: In your first example, the value matcher `equalTo("FAILURE")` is not an argument of hasXPath(). Is that correct?

Comment: well spotted - but even with this fixed, the test still passes no matter what value lies in the `equalTo("ANYTHING")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following format:

```
expect().body("Envelope.Body.preferredPaymentSearch.header.status", equalTo("SUCCESS"))
    .given().body(request)
    .when().post()
```

Comment: this doesn't work.  I get a `"java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed. Expected: an XML document with XPath //soap:Body//*[name()='status']  Actual: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body> `...with remaining soap envelope response

Comment: don't forget that 'request' in my example is a String, not an XML doc. But, I get a valid Soap Envelope in the response so I'm not sure why I can't seem to simply parse it for the expected Xpath value

Comment: given that I have to use my Request as a String, perhaps this binds me to converting the response back into an XML (soap) doc before I can use it in the suggested manner

Comment: @Steerpike I suspect that the hasXPath() syntax you're using is incorrect or you need to specify the Content-Type header.

Comment: hmmm - possibly, though the xpath syntax is definitely correct - I run it against an external tool and it works fine

Comment: @Steerpike I ran a few tests myself and it seems to work if you omit hasXPath() and use an attribute path separated by dots. See the updated answer.

Comment: thanks, so is that using XmlPath instead of Xpath?  That approach gives me an error of `java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
XML path Envelope.Body.status doesn't match.
Expected: SUCCESS
  Actual: `  But I have now added the full Response envelope to the original question so maybe that helps

Comment: @Steerpike See the updated answer. It's based on an example found in the official docs: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#xml-namespaces

Comment: wonderful - thank you for your persistence in helping; very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting out with REST-assured, see if you can evaluate [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) as it is much better for testing SOAP and XML.

Disclaimer: am dev.

Here is the link to the [documentation of the SOAP / XML support](https://github.com/intuit/karate#soap).

XPath expressions are supported natively, and most of the time you would be able to compare two payloads as-is.